# Try_files directive keeps looking for files in /usr/local/nginx/html

Tags: nginx

I can't get my head round why my nginx config keeps looking for files in the wrong directory.

I'm trying to map the `/files` location to `/home/user/toto`. For that I'm using a regex capture group to remove the `/files` prefix and search for the files in the directory  specified in the `root` directive.

```
        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name localhost;

                location ~^\/files\/(.*)$ {
                        root /home/user/toto;
                        try_files /$1/ /$1 ;
                        autoindex off;
                }
       }
```

The problem is I only get 404s. And that's pretty normal because here is what we can find in error.log :

```
2022/07/17 11:27:49 [error] 40358#0: *40 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/test.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /files/test.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

As we can see the `root` directive seems to be completely ignored.

I tried an alternative configuration such as :

```
        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name localhost;

                location ~^\/files\/(.*)$ {
                        # root /home/user/toto;
                        try_files /home/user/toto/$1/ /home/user/toto/$1 ;
                        autoindex off;
                }
       }
```

But the problem is still the same. The only change is that the path now appears in the logs as a prefix for the file name :

```
2022/07/17 11:12:02 [error] 40288#0: *36 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/home/user/toto/test.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /files/test.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the last parameter from the `try_files` directive, so that the `/$1` is being interpreted as an internal redirect instead of a *file* term.

Use:

```
try_files /$1/ /$1 =404;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: Right ; I knew that the last argument could become a rewrite but I thought it would still match files if there were some. Thank you.